# How do I switch between human player and ai in JavaScript Tic Tac Toe with Math.random()?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a human vs AI Tic Tac Toe game and I'm looking for a way to have the AI place a symbol in a cell randomly after the human player. I'm trying to achieve this with Math.random() and using a for loop to generate an id for the AI player. What would be a good way to achieve this? So far it works for the human up until the insertMarker method should be invoked for the AI player.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let huPlayer, computer;
  let huPlayerArr = [], computerArr = [];
  let occupiedCells = [];
  let winningCombos = [
    [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]
  ];

  $cell = $('.cell');

  $('#myModal').modal('show');

  $('.select').click(function() {
    let turnX = 'X';
    let turnO = 'O';
    $(this).attr("data-dismiss", "modal");
    huPlayer = $(this).text() 
    computer = huPlayer === turnX ? turnO: turnX; 
    $('.player').append(`<div class="alert-success">You chose to play as ${huPlayer}</div>`);
  });

  function resetGame() {
    huPlayer = undefined;
    computer = undefined;
    huPlayerArr = [];
    computerArr = [];
    occupiedCells = [];

  }

  function isEmpty(el) {
    if ($.trim($(el).html()) == '') {
      return true;
    };
  }

  function insertMarker(text, val, id) {
    occupiedCells.push(+id);
    text.html(val);
  }

  function isThereAWinner(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
      let check = (arr.indexOf(winningCombos[i][0]) != '-1'
          && arr.indexOf(winningCombos[i][1]) != '-1'
          && arr.indexOf(winningCombos[i][2]) != '-1') 
      if (check) {
        return check;
      }
    }
  }

  $cell.click(function() {
    if (huPlayer === undefined && computer === undefined) {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } 
    else {
      let id = $(this).attr("id");

      if (isEmpty(id)) {
        insertMarker($(this), huPlayer, +id);
        huPlayerArr.push(+id);
        console.log(huPlayerArr);

        if (isThereAWinner(huPlayerArr)) {
          console.log("There's a winner");
          resetGame();
        }
        else if (occupiedCells.length === 9) {
          console.log("Tie game");   
        }
        else {
          let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

          for (let i = 0; i < rand; i++) {
            if (occupiedCells.indexOf(rand) != '-1' && occupiedCells.length != 9) {
              if (occupiedCells.length !== 9) {
                insertMarker($('#' + rand), computer, +rand);
                computerArr.push(rand);
                console.log(computerArr);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell" id="1"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="2"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell" id="4"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="5"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell" id="7"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="8"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="9"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function aiTurn() {


    // while it is the AI's turn
    while(!Turn) {  
        // randomly select from array // select Move
        tryMove = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
        console.log("tryMove " + String(tryMove));
        if(document.getElementById(tryMove).innerHTML == "o") {
            // remove from array
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(tryMove),1);
            // select Ai's turn
            document.getElementById(tryMove).classList.toggle("fade");
             document.getElementById(tryMove).innerHTML = "O";
             document.getElementById(tryMove).style.color = "white";
             // change back to users turn
             Turn = !Turn;
             checkForWin();
         }

        }
```

I made a tic-tac-toe game with an AI and I called this function after the user made their move. You can check out the file in my repository at https://github.com/rileyworstell/UpdatedTicTac/blob/master/TicTacGame/javascript1.js